# Django Insert html into div using jquery .ajax() on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I need help inserting html into an empty div using .ajax(). I have the code below in a django project. The view and url work fine as does the alert message of the ajax .click function. The .ajax() 'success:' property is underlined as unused in pycharm.

The view is as follows:

```
def gen_teams(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

urls:

```
url(r'^gen_teams/$', home_views.gen_teams, name='gen_teams'),
```

main.js:

```
$('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(){
alert('Creating Teams');
var ajaxDiv = $('#ajaxContent');
$.ajax({
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/gen_teams/",
    datatype:"html",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        ajaxDiv.replaceWith(ajaxDiv.html(data));
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <p><button id="ajaxSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Ajax teams</button></p>
    <div id="ajaxContent" class="content-container">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
ajaxDiv.replaceWith(ajaxDiv.html(data));
```

with:

```
$('#ajaxContent').html(data);
```